# Setting up RAID or LVM for a HTPC

Tags: raid, ubuntu-10.04, lvm

I'm working on building a HTPC. I have two 1TB drives that I'd like to combine. I'm thinking about using Ubuntu 10.04. From what I've read I want to use RAID or LVM. I'd prefer to use RAID0 since I'd rather have capacity over redundancy. Problem is I can't find any good tutorials on how how to set this up. Any recommendations or good guides on how to go about doing this? Also, I'd like to be able to add more drives to the array down the road.

Comment: Home Theatre questions really belong on http://superuser.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RAID0 is great for speed, but if all you want is space, then it's not needed and totally redundant and your LVM would be doing exactly the same thing.

Don't install the OS to the big LVM. It's not needed. Partition 100GB or so for the OS and install Ubuntu to that. Then partition the rest along with the other storage drives, and combine them into one big LVM. Then use that as the location to store your video files.

Comment: I agree in principle, but 100GB for the OS is complete overkill. I'm running Ubuntu Server with XBMC on my HTPC and the OS takes up about 2GB. I'd say 10GB for the OS is more than enough.

Comment: Im also against RAID0 for HTPC. If one of disks fail all media files will be lost. Simple LVM or JBOD give a good chance to recover half of files. Personally i prefer many separate disks and manually manage space usage.

Comment: @mmv-ru: wrong, if you lose half of a linearly-joined volume, you're (almost) just as hosed as on RAID0.  your only remote chance of recovering a small fraction of files is if you're _very_ handy with filesystem internals.  no fsck tool would recover anything.